# JFrame won't call paint method?

Tags: java, methods, jframe, paint

So I made Pong in a applet for a project in school but I realized that I can't hand in the project without creating an HTML file, so I'm attempting to change all my code from a applet to a `JFrame`. It all works, but my `paint` method isn't being called, any help will be great. Thanks for the help but to be honest im new to programming so if someone could make the changes to my code and then explain what you did, that would be great

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Main extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{//whatever class holds you main method

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int width = 600;
    int height = width *9/16;
    int Pwidth = 10, Pheight = 50, Px = 30, Py = height / 2-Pwidth, Pv = 3;
    int Ewidth = 10, Eheight = 50, Ex = width - Ewidth - 30, Ey = height / 2-Ewidth - 50;
    double Ev = 2.7;
    int Bwidth = 10, Bheight = 10, Bx = width / 2 + 50, By = height / 2, Bvx = 3, Bvy = 3;
    int TimeD = 0;
    int Ms = 0, sec = 0, min = 0;
    int Pscore = 0, Escore = 0, Pwinx = 800, Pwiny = height / 2, Ewinx = 800, Ewiny = height / 2;
    boolean Bleft = true, Bright = false, Bup = true, Bdown = false;
    boolean Pup = false, Pdown = false;
    boolean Pa = false;
    String string = new String();

public static JFrame frame;//public and static so other classes can access it. Might want to use a getter and setter here

public Main(){
     frame=new JFrame("Pong, A game re-made by Camron Warren");// Create new JFrame
     frame.setSize(width,height);//Set the size of the window
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Make sure all processes are closed when the window is closed
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Centers window
     frame.setVisible(true);//Make the window visible
     Thread th = new Thread(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        th.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     new Main();//instantiate the Main class, this has to happen
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        if(Pscore >= 5){
            Pwinx = 100;
            Py = height / 2 - Pheight / 2;
            Bx = width / 2 - Bwidth;
            By = height /2 - Bheight /2;
        }
        if(Escore >= 5){
            Ewinx = 400;
            Py = height / 2-Pwidth;
            Bx = width / 2 - Bwidth;
            By = height /2;
        }
        if(Escore >= 5 && Pa == true){
            Pscore = 0;
            Escore = 0;
            Ewinx = 800;
            Ms = 0;
            sec = 0;
            min = 0;
        }
        if(Pscore >= 5 && Pa == true){
            Pscore = 0;
            Escore = 0;
            Pwinx = 800;
            Ms = 0;
            sec = 0;
            min = 0;
        }
        //ball movement class
        ballMovement();

        //TIME COUNTER
        Ms++;
         if(Ms >= 60){
             sec++;
             Ms = 0;
         }
         if(sec >= 60){
             min++;
             sec = 0;
         }
        //BALLMOVEMENT
        if(Bleft == true){
            Bx-=Bvx;
        }
        if(Bright == true){
            Bx+=Bvx;
        }
        if(Bup == true){
            By-=Bvy;
        }
        if(Bdown == true){
            By+=Bvy;
        }
        //BALLHITBOX
        if(By <= 0){
            Bup = false;
            Bdown = true;
        }
        if(By + Bheight >= height){
            Bdown = false;
            Bup = true;
        }
        //SCORE SYSTEM
        if(Bx <= 0){
            Escore++;
            Bx = width / 2 - Bwidth;
            By = height / 2;
        }

        if(Bx+Bwidth >= width){
            Pscore++;
            Bx = width /2 - Bwidth;
            By = height / 2;
        }
        //PHITBOX
        if(Bx+Bwidth >= Px && Bx <= Px+Pwidth && By+Bheight >= Py && By <= Py+Pheight){
            System.out.println("Phit");
            Bleft = false;
            Bright = true;
        }
        //EHITBOX
        if(Bx+Bwidth >= Ex && Bx <= Ex + Ewidth && By+Bheight >= Ey && By <= Ey + Eheight){
            System.out.println("Ehit");
            Bright = false; 
            Bleft = true;
        }
        //PMOVEMENT
        if(Pup == true){
            Py-=Pv;
        }
        if(Pdown == true){
            Py+=Pv;
        }
        //PHITBOX/APPLETHITBOX
        if(Py <= 0){
            Py = 0;
        }
        if(Py + Pheight >= height){
            Py = height - Pheight;
        }
        //EHITBOX/APPLETHITBOX
        if(Ey <= 0){
            Ey = 0;
        }
        if(Ey + Eheight >= height){
            Ey = height - Eheight;
        }
        //REPAINT
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
public void ballMovement()
{

    if(By >= Ey)
    {
        Ey += Ev;
    }
    if(By <= Ey)
    {
        Ey -= Ev;
    }

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){
         Pup = true;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S){
         Pdown = true;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
         Pup = true;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
         Pdown = true;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F1){
        Pa = true;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W){
         Pup = false;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S){
         Pdown = false;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
         Pup = false;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
         Pdown = false;
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_F1){
        Pa = false;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void update(Graphics g) {
        Graphics offgc;
        Image offscreen = null;
        Dimension d = size();

        offscreen = createImage(d.width, d.height);
        offgc = offscreen.getGraphics();
        offgc.setColor(getBackground());
        offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        offgc.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(offgc);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
        }

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(Px, Py, Pwidth, Pheight);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(Ex, Ey, Ewidth, Eheight);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(Bx, By, Bwidth, Bheight);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);

    g.drawString("Score: " + Pscore, 20, 20);

    g.drawString("Score " + Escore , width - 60, 20);

    g.drawString("Time played: " + min + ": " + sec, width / 2 - 50, 20);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(width / 2, height, 1, height);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Pong: a game re-made by Camron Warren", 10, height - 10);

    g.drawString("Congrat's, you win!", Pwinx, Pwiny);
    g.drawString("Press F1 to play again!", Pwinx, Pwiny + 10);

    g.drawString("Enemy win's", Ewinx, Ewiny);
    g.drawString("Press F1 to play again!", Ewinx, Ewiny + 10);
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`, 2) In the same token, don't use deprecated methods. They're deprecated for a reason. 3) You've got a Swing GUI, so don't do AWT graphics. Instead of using `update(...)` and `paint(...)`, override the `paintComponent(...)` method. 4) Don't forget to call the `super.paintComponent(g)` in your override. 5) Read the Swing graphics tutorials as they will contain very useful information that is pertinent to your problem and your code.

Comment: To start with, JPanel is already double buffered, so you don't need to do your offscreen buffer. AFAIK, Swing won't call the update method, but I could be wrong. Painting in Swing is generally achieved by overriding paibtComponent. You should also be calling super.paint (or super.paintComponent if you do it properly)

Comment: Also, avoid KeyListeners and instead favor Key Bindings which is much more flexible with regards to component focus.

Comment: Thanks for the help but to be honest im new to programming so if someone could make the changes to my code and then explain what you did, that would be great

Comment: You should also consider using JLabel and/or JButtons to display options to the user. You could then use a CardLayout to switch between the menu and game views

Comment: I would do that Mad but JFrames are new territory for me, I only today, an hour ago to be precise learnt the basics of them.

Comment: `"...but to be honest im new to programming so if someone could make the changes to my code and then explain what you did, that would be great..."` -- that's asking others to do your work for you which would be cheating both academically and also cheating yourself out of invaluable coding and self exploration experiences. Please never make this type of statement on this site. Instead ask for advice, and try to use that advice to help you do the coding yourself. Honestly, that's how you learn. You can always post your mistakes as edits to your question, and we'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: Thats y I asked for you to explain it, idk what people mean by their explanations so I asked for an example.

Comment: Please ask for clarification. Let us know what specifically confuses you.

Comment: My paint method isn't being painted and I dont know why, please give me an example of how to fix it and explain how your code works so I can learn from it. I cant be clearer than that